# using ARIA role="none" to remove an item from accessibility tree

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is it considered valid to remove a "generic" item (eg. `<div>` or `<custom-tag>`) from accessibility tree by applying it a role"none" attribute?

```
<custom-tag role="none"><...></custom-tag>
```

Answer (score 4):

This will not remove it from the accessibility tree as such, but convert the item to a generic container (like a `<div>` or `<span>`) within the accessibility tree and remove all semantic meaning.

So all the content will still be part of the accessibility tree.

It is far more likely you want `aria-hidden="true"` to remove something from the accessibility tree.

However be aware that any focusable items within an item with `aria-hidden="true"` are still focusable so you will also have to add `tabindex="-1"` to them.

The real question you should ask is "why am I hiding this from screen readers" as it is far more likely there is a different solution you need (such as making the item accessible or just removing it entirely for all users with `display: none` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Screen readers such as JAWS and NVDA are quite good at interpretting generic or custom tags in the accessibility tree. So, unless you're doing something unconventional where you need to strip the semantic information from the accessibility tree, it's seldom necessary to use `role="none"`.

You may want to use `role="none"` to prevent unintended screen reader behaviour, such as the screen reader interpretting data in a table where the table is only used for the visual layout.

By contrast, one should be careful applying `aria-hidden="true"` to any elements because this attribute hides both the element it is applied to as well as any descendant of that element. This means that the screen reader won't report this element, or anything inside it, at all. So be certain that is what you're looking to do before you use it.

I'd agree with Graham that you probably want to consider why you're hiding elements from screen readers in the first place. ARIA should be used sparingly to guide the intended behaviour of screen readers, rather than applied to elements without first considering why it's necessary in the first place.